# Doxygen auto param generate

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, comments, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

Is there any tool or plugin for visual studio c++ to generate an auto pre-structure of doxygen comments, based on the definition of function?

Thank you.

something like this example:

```
/**
 *****************************************************************************************
 *  @brief      
 *
 *  @usage      
 * 
 *  @param      
 *  @param      
 *
 *  @return     
 ****************************************************************************************/

int TestAPI2(
    int argument1,
    int argument2
    );
```

Comment: You can use [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for this (note that it's not free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest instead you document inline with the parameters

```
int TestAPI2(
    int argument1, /**< does this **/
    int argument2 /**< does that, should never be a prime number, 
                       and I keep wanting to go on and on about it. **/
    );
```

Any tool that automatically documents the parameters will produce useless documentation someone else has to fill in anyway.

You can set `WARN_NO_PARAMDOC = YES` in your doxygen file if you want a list of parameters that have not been documented.

That said, you could try [Gostdoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) if you have some process constraint where meaningless comments are "better" than no comments.

Comment: Of note, inline documentation makes it easier to keep stuff orderly when parameters change than documenting in the method header.